# Maven fails to publish artifact to AWS S3

Tags: maven, amazon-s3, wagon

I am trying to upload a jar to S3 via gitlab CI pipeline.
On `deploy` stage a run a job with a script.

`- mvn -s ../aws-settings.xml deploy`

my `aws-settings.xml` file looks like this (AWS access keys are set in gitlab CI as environment variables)

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>artifact-s3-repo</id>
            <username>${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}</username>
            <password>${env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}</password>
            <configuration>
                <region>${env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}</region>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

and in my `pom.xml` I set distribution managment as

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>artifact-s3-repo</id>
            <url>s3://<myartifactbucketname>/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

my pipeline fails on `deploy` stage with the following output

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project <my-project-name>: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access s3://<myartifactbucketname>/ with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access s3://<myartifactbucketname>/ using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

I need some hints to configure the connection to aws properly (without adding additional plugins if possible). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to publish artifact to S3 via `maven deploy` , but I implemented AWS CLI commands in my pipeline script